# Creating a MYSQL view from equations

Tags: mysql, sql, view

Using MYSQL, I need some help creating a view from multiple tables and performing some calculations.

My problem is that the equation adds extra decimal places to my value, is there a way to proceed and avoid those extra decimal places?
Here is my SQL statement for the view

```
    CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`Tosby`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_products`  AS  select `tbl_products`.`id` AS 
`id`,`tbl_products`.`name` AS `name`,`tbl_products`.`descr` AS `descr`,`tbl_products`.`image` AS `image`,`tbl_categories`.`name` AS 
`category`,((`tbl_products`.`cost` * (`tbl_tax`.`amount` / 100)) + `tbl_products`.`cost`) AS `cost`,
`tbl_restaurants`.`name` AS `restaurant` from (((`tbl_products` join `tbl_categories` on((`tbl_products`.`category` = `tbl_categories`.`id`))) 
join `tbl_tax` on((`tbl_products`.`tax` = `tbl_tax`.`id`))) 
join `tbl_restaurants` on((`tbl_products`.`owner` = `tbl_restaurants`.`id`))) ;
```

The line giving the problem is this

```
    ((`tbl_products`.`cost` * (`tbl_tax`.`amount` / 100)) + `tbl_products`.`cost`) AS `cost`,
```

How could I remove the extra decimal places added in the length of the field? Note that all those fields used in the equation have integers as the datatype and the length is 4 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `round()`

```
SELECT ROUND(135.37589567657, 2); it will return 135.38
```

so in you  case

```
round (((`tbl_products`.`cost` * (`tbl_tax`.`amount` / 100)) + `tbl_products`.`cost`),n)
```

Where n = the number of decimal places you want to have

Comment: Would you please explain to me why it was returning four decimal places despite dividing whole numbers by 100

Answer (score 1):

use `format()`

reference [link](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-mathematical-format.php)

```
SELECT FORMAT(12324.2573, 3); //output 12324.257
```

Comment: This does return the formatted value as a string and that may not be what I wanted as the data type of the of the field is supposed to be decimal